# Has the react-native openai-api module been modified to access the ChatGPT API?

Tags: react-native, openai-api, chatgpt-api

Has the react-native openai-api module been modified to access ChatGPT API?
  When using expo, I get the following error :

> WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): 
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

using `openai.ChatCompletion.create` seems not to work in react-native

code :

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, TextInput, Button, FlatList, Text } from "react-native";
import OpenAI from "openai-api";

const openai = new OpenAI("YOUR_API_KEY");

export default function App() {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [responseText, setResponseText] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    async function generateResponse() {
      if (messages.length > 0) {
        const response = await openai.ChatCompletion.create({
          model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
          messages,
        });
        print(response);
        setResponseText(response.choices[0].text);
      }
    }
    generateResponse();
  }, [messages]);
```

Comment: `const openai = new OpenAI("YOUR_API_KEY");` you missed to give your api key

Answer (score 0):

As of **4th March 2023** the [openai-api](https://github.com/Njerschow/openai-api) library does not yet support the chat completion functionality. So the `ChatCompletion` property that you are trying to access does not exist, hence you are getting the `Cannot read property 'create' of undefined` message.

I would instead strongly advise you to use the official [openai](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openai-api) library which works in the browser and fully supports the new chat completions.

You can do this by changing your code to the following and replacing the `YOUR API KEY` string to your own key:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, TextInput, Button, FlatList, Text } from "react-native";
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from 'openai';

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: "YOUR API KEY",
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

export default function App() {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [responseText, setResponseText] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    async function generateResponse() {
      if (messages.length > 0) {
        const response = await openai.createChatCompletion({
          model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
          messages,
        });
        print(response);
        setResponseText(completion.data.choices[0].message.content);
      }
    }
    generateResponse();
  }, [messages]);
```